# Excel file writing error with Table Styles in EPPlus

Tags: c#, epplus

I have a requirement to write report the excel sheet with a style but

I am facing the error **Tablename is not valid Parameter name: Name** while trying to load the **data table** in an excel sheet using epplus with styles like below

```
 if (_ds.Tables[i].Rows.Count > 0)
 {
   _resultworkSheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(_ds.Tables[i], true, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Medium9);
 }
```

If I try to write the **data table** to excel sheet without table styles like below I am not facing any error

```
if (_ds.Tables[i].Rows.Count > 0)
{
  _resultworkSheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(_ds.Tables[i], true);
}
```

I am confused what could be causing the error while trying to load the excel sheet with styles anyone please shed a light on this to clear the error

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the method your using, I do it like this

```
SelectedTable = Worksheet.Tables.Add(Range, tableName);
SelectedTable.TableStyle = _defaultTableStyle;
```

So if you grab the returned data and then set the style:

```
var data = _resultworkSheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(_ds.Tables[i], true);
data.TableStyle = OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Medium9;
```

It's not one liner, but if it works :D

Comment: When I try ``var data = _resultworkSheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(_ds.Tables[i], true);
data.TableStyle = OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Medium9;`` it shows error that ExcelRangeBase does not contain a defnition for TableStyle

Comment: What version of epplus are you using? The code I wrote was for the free last version.... I think 4.5.1. I've also never used the LoadFromDataTable, so not sure about the difference of how a table is created vs dumping the data and then converting the range to a table.

Comment: I am using Version 5.6.3 it is a version with or without license, if there is license and you are using it for non commercial purpose you can use it with ``ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;``